# quartz scheduler wrongly classifying a job to recover

Tags: java, playframework, quartz-scheduler

When I am running two instances of the application in a machine. One of the instance picks up the job for execution and other instance picks up the same job for recovery.

As per the documentation, below property should take care of distributing the work across multiple instances. However, one of the instance is picking the same job for recovery.

```
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered = true
```

Using Quartz-2.3.2

quartz.properties

```
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId = AUTO
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = JobScheduler
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 1

org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource = ss
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered = true

org.quartz.dataSource.ss.driver = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
org.quartz.dataSource.ss.URL = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ss
org.quartz.dataSource.ss.user = root
org.quartz.dataSource.ss.password = password
```

Code snippet to sscheduleJob

```
JobDetail jobDetail = JobBuilder
        .newJob(JobService.class)
        .requestRecovery(true)
        .withIdentity(promotionJob.getId().toString(), RulesPromotionConstants.JOB_SCHEDULER_GROUP)
        .build();
    // see if jobdatamap needs to be added above

    Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder
        .newTrigger()
        .forJob(jobDetail)
        .startAt(Date.from(Instant.ofEpochMilli(promotionJob.getScheduledAt())))
        .withSchedule(SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule().withMisfireHandlingInstructionFireNow())
        .withIdentity(promotionJob.getId().toString(), RulesPromotionConstants.JOB_TRIGGER_SCHEDULER_GROUP)
        .build();

    rulesPromotionScheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
```

Below code snippet, if condition is being executed while the one of the instance is already executing the same job.

```
if (jobExecutionContext.isRecovering()) {
    loggerService.getLogger().debug("JobId {} is being recovered",job.getId());
    undoPreparationState(job);
}
```

Note:- The job takes few seconds to few minutes to execute.